# how to judge which object to be synchronized in java thread?

Tags: java, synchronized

I think I can use any object to be synchronized as block such as:

```
synchronized(new Object()){
}
```

but I often see to synchronized one hashmap when need hashmap be thread safe.but I think I can use one other object to instead of the hashmap.  So which object be synchronized best?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Doing `synchronized (new Object()) { ... }` is of no use at all, since no other thread would ever get hold of the object which is locked anyway.

You should synchronize on an object "guarding" a resource. Obviously, if several threads needs access to the same resource, the object guarding the resource needs to be available to both threads.

Perhaps you've seen this:

```
class SomeClass {

    final private Object lock = new Object();

    void method() {
        ...
        synchronized (lock) {
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

That is however very different from doing `synchronized (new Object())` since in the above code, the same object is used for all threads executing the method.

> *but I often see to synchronized one hashmap when need hashmap be thread safe.but I think i can use one other object to instead of the hashmap. So which object be synchrozied best?*

Right, if a hash map is the resource to be shared among several threads, then it is common to synchronize on that object.

```
synchronized (someHashMap) {
    ... use someHashMap in a thread safe way ...
}
```

And yes, you could just as well synchronize on some member field `lock = new Object()` as well. In fact, synchronizing using a dedicated lock object is sometimes preferred, since it doesn't interfere with the synchronized methods of the object you're protecting.

Answer (score 5):

Synchronizing using a *new object* each time is not making anything more thread safe. You need to reuse the **same** synchronization object each time.

Other then that you can use another "sync object" than the data structure you are locking (but you need to make sure you use the same reference everywhere! ;) ).

---

In fact, many uses a dedicated sync object (e.g `private final Object sync = new Object()`) within the object since synchronizing `this` could be dangerous when another thread can lock up the object somewhere else in the code.

Comment: Many thanks to you.  do you mean that?  I can use any object as synchronized object, but I should keep synchronized objest be some in other code if i want to thead safe?

Comment: You will need to guard the data-structure you touch by several threads with the *same* locking mechanizm. If you use a `synchronized` block that needs to lock the exact same reference.

Comment: +1 You should be careful when synchronizing to known classes rather than dedicated objects unless you know exactly what that class does.  If that class has some sort of synchronization built in, you could be causing a deadlock conflicting with code internal to that class that synchronizes to itself.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, it would be a bad idea to do `synchronized(new Object())`, because each thread would create its own objects, so the synchronization would be meaningless.

In the example where you want synch access to an existing object, synchronizing on that object makes sense.  There's no benefit to creating some other object to synchronize on.

However, if you want to do something more fancy to increase concurrency -- like, say, divide the possible keys of the map up into several sets, and protect each of those sets with a different lock -- then creating separate objects to synchronize on could be useful.  But I wouldn't bother with something like this until you've really identified a performance issue that needs to be addressed.

Comment: -1 for "There's no benefit to creating some other object to synchronize on."  If you synchronize to an existing object which synchronizes to itself inside its own methods, you could be causing a deadlock without realizing it.

Comment: @ErickRobertson - huh?  A deadlock requires locks being acquired on two different objects.  If a thread acquires a lock on object A, then calls a synchronized method in that object, it already holds the lock, so there's no issue.

Comment: In a multithreaded system, other threads may be interacting with that object as well.  There are several ways another thread may already have a lock on the object and be trying to grab a lock that the first thread already has while it's trying to synchronize to the object.

Answer (score 3):

Nobody seems to have mentioned it but depending on your requirements, using a thread safe object in the first place **might** enable you to remove all the locking logic.

In the case of `HashMap`, there is `ConcurrentHashMap`, which is a thread safe version with a few additional atomic operations (putIfAbsent etc.).

Answer (score 2):

It really doesn't matter, as long as you use the same one each time. I personally prefer using the actual object that needs synchronization (like your `HashMap`) because it conveys more clearly that I'm synchronizing it, and another object instance (with possible messy variables) isn't needed.

And note that if you're actually using:

```
synchronized(new Object()) {
    // ...
}
```

then you're doing it wrong, as `new Object()` creates a new object each time; you need to keep the same reference for it to synchronize properly.